# How to convert a string to a string property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to write a function using Typescript that takes 2 arguments in which the second argument is always of type string. The function should apply the second argument on the first argument as its property

Example:

```
let x = measure('Hello', 'length'); // should return 'Hello'.length
// => x = 5
```

How can I convert the string 'length' to be a property of 'Hello' to return 'Hello'.length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you:

```
function measure(obj: any, property: string): any {
    return obj[property];
}

let x = measure('Hello', 'length');
console.log(x); // 5
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20measure(obj%3A%20any%2C%20property%3A%20string)%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20obj%5Bproperty%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%20%3D%20measure('Hello'%2C%20'length')%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(x)%3B%20%2F%2F%205))

---

#### Edit

Or even better:

```
function measure<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, property: K): T[K] {
    return obj[property];
}
```

In this version the compiler can infer the type of the returned value, and will also enforce that only existing property names are used, for example:

```
let x = measure('Hello', 'lengthy'); // error
```

Comment: Nice, but the second one wouldn't work if the property name was passed as a variable, however.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Right, unless you define the variable to be of type `keyof string` (or cast to it).

Comment: Yep, and the cast case gets goofy because the return type is then the union of the types of _all_ properties. :) Interesting case.

Comment: Many thanks guys, the first solution was more convenient for the rest of my code since the second argument is passed as a variable and the first argument is not always string.